# Why component passed in props does not work when called as function? "React has detected a change in the order of Hooks called"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I've prepared simple sanbox to ilustrate one example in which i'm passing component and then calling it like function, and second one which works just by calling it like normal component. To switch between working and not working examples comment or uncomment adequatly named components in `App.tsx`
https://codesandbox.io/s/delicate-night-mtf33d?file=/src/App.tsx

Also the not working example will work if `useStyles()` would be deleted from `ListItem`, but in console log it show difference in hook called `useContext()`

My goal is to pass component as prop or child and also be able to populate that child with data via props and make `InfiniteList` generic and reausable.

Could someone please explain how to (if possible) use passed function as Component not just as function. And why do i see error i've mentioned when using it as function but not when using as Component.

Answer (score 0):

Why you did not destructured `props` for `export default function ListItem(params: Item, ref?: LegacyRef<HTMLDivElement> | null)` component, in the `not working folder`. Or I am wrong?

Comment: I did that because i had this warning 
`Type '(pageNumber: number, patientId: number) => PaginationCallerOutput<Item>' is not assignable to type '(pageNumber: number, patientId: number) => PaginationCallerOutput<{ params: Item; ref?: LegacyRef<HTMLDivElement> | undefined; }>'.
  Type 'PaginationCallerOutput<Item>' is not assignable to type 'PaginationCallerOutput<{ params: Item; ref?: LegacyRef<HTMLDivElement> | undefined; }>'.
    Property 'params' is missing in type 'Item' but required in type '{ params: Item; ref?: LegacyRef<HTMLDivElement> | undefined; }'` which is strange for me.

Comment: Because it seems like it resolves generic `T` in `InfiniteList` to parameters/props from `ListItem` if i destructure them

Comment: also it changes nothing in terms of error which is still `Rendered more hooks than during the previous render.`

Comment: Give us examples (working and not working) in CodeSandBox. Actually I do not get how you use your components in `App.js`

Comment: They both render the same thing!

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/delicate-night-mtf33d?file=/src/App.tsx here it is, sorry, it reverted `App.tsx`  and `package.json` to default one. Just comment `<Working patientId={1} />` and uncomment `<NotWorking patientId={1} />` to get not working one.